# Display only the day on a weekley calendar

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I am making a new site home page and wanted to put a calendar webpart in it.  However the Monthly calendar view takes up to much screen real-estate, so I switched it to a weekly view instead.  However, on the weekly view it lists the time slots from 7AM to 6PM and takes up more space than the monthly calendar. Is there a way make it so that the time slots are not visible and the calendar is only showing days/events like a monthly calendar but only a week at a time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to ask the exact same question. This probably isn't the most elegant solution, but the way I have solved this for now is to set the web part to a fixed height of 155 pixels. That way I see just the all day events. Problem is that setting maxes to just 5 events in a day, and then they fall below the scroll bar. Fewer than 5 events still shows a little of the time slots. Hope that helps a little, and I'll continue to follow this one for a better solution.

Comment: thanks for the tip! ill look into that.  However, for a better solution I think its either going to require creating your own custom webpart (or if you find one online) or just dealing with it. but thanks!